# Powershell Script to move multiple unknown files into correct locations

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a script for use when we perform manual data transfers at work, this can be tedious to perform when users have a ton of random data in random locations. I want to move those items from the old location on the old drive to our network location and then pull it back down. What I have below is a beta version of what I am looking to do, my issue is that I am unable to figure out why I am unable to find the current logged in user and exclude certain accounts.

```
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = 'C:\TextFiles'
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}

$Include=@("*.*")
$Path=@("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents","C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures")

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include $Include -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination C:\TextFiles
```

Mind you more will be added to this but I am unsure how to get the current user and have it exclude our administrator account on the units.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable named `USERDOMAIN` and `USERNAME` to determine the currently logged on user.

```
if ($env:UserName -eq 'Trevor.Sullivan') {
    # Do something
}
```

To take it one step further, you could build an array of the user accounts that you want to exclude, and then check to see if the currently logged on user account is contained in that array. Here is an example:

```
# Build the list of excluded users
$ExcludedUserList = @(
      'User1'
    , 'User2'
    , 'User3'
    , 'User4'
    );

# Check if user is contained in exclusion list
if ('User5' -notin $ExcludedUserList) {
    # Do something here
}
```

Comment: If I am reading this correct then if 'User5' is say, John Smith, and it is not in the exclusion list then it would do a data transfer for John Smith correct? Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated.